# pacman -Syyu error: could not import key from Trusted User

Tags: upgrade, manjaro, pacman, signature

> DISTRIB_ID=ManjaroLinux
>
> DISTRIB_RELEASE=17.1.6
>
> DISTRIB_CODENAME=Hakoila

I installed manjaro on an old laptop today and am in the process of trying to update it.

just using `pacman -Syyu` eventually gave me

```
(383/383) checking keys in keyring
downloading required keys...
:: Import PGP Key KEY, "Brad Fanella <cesura@archlinux.org>", 
created: 2018-03-2? [Y/n] Y
error: key "Brad Fanella <cesura@archlinux.org>" could not be imported
error: required key missing from keyring
error: failed to commit transaction (unexpected error)
```

I tried this sequence, to no avail:

```
sudo pacman-key --init
sudo pacman-key --populate archlinux manjaro
sudo pacman-key --refresh-keys
sudo pacman -Syy
sudo pacman -S manjaro-keyring archlinux-keyring
sudo pacman -Syyu
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1**

Tried `pacman-key --recv-keys F382BBBD` and got this:

```
gpg: key 81A402D4F382BBBD was created 6 days in the future (time warp or clock problem)
gpg: key 81A402D4F382BBBD: no valid user IDs
gpg: this may be caused by a missing self-signature
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:           w/o user IDs: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

From **EDIT 1** output,

I updated the clock using `sudo ntpdate -vu time.nist.gov`

then `pacman-key --recv-keys F382BBBD` and voilà.

That was annoyingly simple.

Answer (score 1):

The following is for archlinux however apples to other Linux distros too.
To correct an invalid KEY one needs to do the following:

```
rm -fr /etc/pacman.d/gnupg
pacman-key --init
pacman-key --populate archlinux
```

say the key throwing an error is in Blackarch then is also needed to :

```
sudo pacman-key --populate blackarch
```

and finally

```
sudo pacman -Sy archlinux-keyring
sudo pacman-key --populate archlinux
sudo pacman-key --refresh-keys
```